# how to use @inject of mobx with react in typescript(tsx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

here is my store code:

```
export  default class welcome {
    @observable username= "asd";
}
```

and my component.tsx: a easy div component,want to show the value of welcome's username

```
@inject("welcome")
@observer

export default class WelcomePage extends React.Component<any,any> {

render() {
    console.log(this.props.welcome.username)
    return <div>
        {this.props.welcome.username}
        <button >123213</button>
        hello react!</div>

}
}
```

my entry:

```
render(<Provider welcome={welcome}>
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

when i debug or log the this.props.welcome.username ,it is undefined.how to fix this or how to use @inject of mobx in typescript (tsx)，i have read some demo/example on github:

https://github.com/contacts-mvc/mobx-react-typescript

they all use {key:value} to inject the props.not @inject anotation.

Comment: i know why now,because store must be an object .i passed a class. XD.

Comment: A class is a function. A function is an object.